# Include div with an ID twice, possible?

Tags: php, javascript

I want to include a file(menu.php) twice, but inside that file I have a div with an ID.
Here is menu.php :

```
<?php
    for ($b = 1; $b <= 10; $b++)
    {
        $width = 220;
        $width /= $b;
?>
    <div id="menuH<?php print $b; ?>" style="display: none;">
    <?php
        for ($a = 1; $a <= $b; $a++)
        {
            print '<div class="voorbeeld_menuH" style="width: '.($width - 1).'px;" ><b>M</b></div>';
        }
    ?>
    </div>
<?php
    }
    for ($b = 1; $b <= 10; $b++)
    {
?>
        <div id="menuV<?php print $b; ?>" style="display: none;">
        <?php
            for ($a = 1; $a <= $b; $a++)
            {
                print '<div class="voorbeeld_menuV" ><b>M</b></div>';
            }
        ?>
        </div>
<?php
    }
?>
```

Javascript code :

```
function menu(dropdown)
{
    var myindex_M = dropdown.selectedIndex;
    var waarde_M = dropdown.options[myindex_M].value;
    var i = 1;
    var a = 1;

    if(waarde_M == " - - - -")
    {
        for(i = 1;1 <= 10;i++)
        {    
            document.getElementById("menuH" + i).style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById("menuV" + i).style.display = "none";
        }
    }
    for(i = 1;i <= 10;i++)
    {
        if(waarde_M == "Menu H " + i)
        {
            document.getElementById("menuH" + i).style.display = "";
            for(a = 1;a <= 10;a++)
            {
                if(a == i) { continue; }
                document.getElementById("menuH" + a).style.display = "none";
            }   
        }
    }
}
```

Where I want to include this :

```
<?php
    include("Menu.php");

    for ($b = 1; $b <= 5; $b++)
    {
?>
        <div id="content" style="display: none;">
        <?php
            for ($a = 1; $a <= $b; $a++)
            {
                print '<div class="voorbeeld_content'.$b.'"><b>Content</b></div>';
            }
        ?>
        </div>
<?php
    }
?>
```

and include here too :

```
<?php
    include("Menu.php");

    for ($b = 1; $b <= 5; $b++)
    {
?>
        <div id="header" style="display: none;">
        <?php
            for ($a = 1; $a <= $b; $a++)
            {
                print '<div class="vooorbeeld_header.$b.'"><b>H</b></div>';
            }
        ?>
        </div>
<?php
    }
?>
```

The problem is, the javascript code only works on menu.php, and not in the content.php and header.php, because of the ID tag, how can I solve this?

Comment: I know, but is there any option to solve this problem?

Comment: Use unique IDs or classes. In the latter case I'd suggest you to add jQuery so you can easily query elements by classname etc. (`$('.class')`)

Comment: Could you give me an example of jQuery?

Comment: http://www.jquery.com has lots of docs and some tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

the [id has to be unique](http://webdesign.about.com/od/css/f/blfaqmultiIDs.htm). always. thats all. change your code to give different id's to the different incudes of the menue or use classes instead.

to quote the [W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2):

> *Attribute definitions*
>
> **id:** This attribute assigns a name to an element. This name must be unique in a document.

Comment: How can you change the display of classes inside javascript?

Answer (score 0):

You can not give same id to same kind of control or to other kind of controls. that is it's unique identity. you have to change the code in a way that every control has unique id through out the web page...

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have two or more elements with the same IDs on the page. JavaScript won't select both elements because the ID has to be unique. Try to find a way to put unique IDs on your elements.